# ARM cp14 hardware breakpoints

Tags: debugging, arm, breakpoints

Can somebody give an example of ASM code setting ARM7 (32bit) cp14 hardware breakpoints?
The breakpoint has to be hit on instruction address match.
Thumb or ARM instruction set.
With context matching. Context is VMId + ProcessId.
Any working examples for any ARM implementations, supporting hardware breakpoints, are greatly appreciated.

The topic is new for me. So if the question is not very correct or information is missing, please ask )

Thank you all.